# Processing time after notice of approval

Tags: usa, immigration, student-visa

I am on an F-1 visa and applied for OPT on May 25th, 2018. My OPT was approved on August 24th and I have received my notice of approval. However as of August 31, the online status says that my card is under production. Are there any estimates of typical production times after approval ?

EDIT: I received the notice that my card was mailed a week after notice of approval and another week to receive my card in the mail (it was a long weekend in between mailing of the card and the card being received).

Comment: Glad to hear you got the card, and thanks for editing your question to tell how it went. Could you please post that part as an answer on this page?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my timeline of the process:

1. Sent documents for approval : May 24th
2. Received at the dropbox center in Texas : May 25th. However, when I checked this date on the DHS website, it displayed May 30th.
3. Case was approved: August 23rd
4. New card is being produced: August 24th
5. Card was mailed to me: September 1st.
6. Received the card : September 6th.